# getting json file in bukkit

Tags: java, json, bukkit

I'm trying to get my JSON in my plugin, but it doesn't work. Here is my code to get it and here is the path: `static File json = new File("config.JSON");`. I tried to use the GetDataFoder() method but I can't because I'm using static methods.

```java
public class JSONReader extends JavaPlugin {
    static File json = new File("config.JSON");

    static File getJSON() {
        return json;
    }

    static JSONObject setupJson() {
        try {
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            Object parsed = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(json.getPath()));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parsed;
            return jsonObject;
        } catch (ParseException | IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than image and also post error log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All paths are evaluated relative to your *working directory*, which is the one containing your server executable. Bukkit provides convenience methods for file access through [`JavaPlugin`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html):

- Referencing files within the plugin's data folder

  ```
  File f = new File(getDataFolder(), "config.json");
  ```
- Retrieving files within the plugin's jar

  ```
  InputStream is = getResource("config.json");
  ```

Comment: It tells me ```Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getDataFolder() from the type JavaPlugin``` and I need it to be static because I want to get it from other files

Comment: @Raffon Consider turning your JavaPlugin into a Singleton

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: There are numerous guides here and on other sites. In this case you need a slightly modified implementation, where the instance field is assigned to `this` in your `onLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

the path is relative to the Bukkit server jar so you need to go from there to your file `/plugins/plugin-name/config.json`

Comment: I have tried to put ```/plugins/FallenKingdoms/config.json``` but it doesn't work :c